# Subnumbering Equations Under the actual equation number

Tags: equations, subequations

I am trying to write an optimization problem like below using **eqnarray**:

```
Max   z =a + b   (1)
s.t   a > 1     
      b < 4
```

But I want to write the sub-equation numbers as `(1.a)` and `(1.b)` like below:

```
Max   z =a + b   (1)
s.t   a > 1      (1.a)
      b < 4      (1.b)
```

How can I write it? please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy with `alignat`, using `\tag` for suppressing the advancement of the numbering and setting the referenced equation number instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:foo}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\max        &\quad& z &= a + b   \tag{\ref{eq:foo}} \\
\text{s.t.} &     & a &> 1 \\
            &     & b &< 4
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

You can of course add labels also for the two conditions.

[image]

Comment: i picked this answer as this looks easy for me. thanks @egreg

Answer (score 3):

First off: [Don't use eqnarray.](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) It's badly deprecated. Use one of the multi-line equation environments of the `amsmath` package instead.

If your formatting need is one-off, it's probably not worth the overhead to set up a separate environment. Instead, simply use `\tag` and `\ref` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\max   z =a + b   \label{eq:1} \\
\text{s.t.}\quad           a > 1     \tag{\ref{eq:1}a} \\
\phantom{\text{s.t.}}\quad b < 4     \tag{\ref{eq:1}b} 
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

If you need to use this more than once, you may wish to use combined `equation` (for the main equation) and `gather` or `align` (for the conditions) environments. (The advantage of combining these environments is that LaTeX will, if need be, find a good pagebreak.) E.g.,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\ajustspaceandequationnumber{%
   \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}
   \vspace{-\abovedisplayskip}
   \addtocounter{equation}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\max   z =a + b  
\end{equation}
\ajustspaceandequationnumber
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{s.t.}\quad  &a > 1   \\
 & b < 4     
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice regarding eqnarray and ur answer @Mico.