# Subnumber equations continuing after a line of text

Tags: numbering, subequations

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264620/subnumbering-equations-under-the-actual-equation-number?rq=1) question (but not enough to be a duplicate), I am trying to have a theorem where there is a line of text in-between some of the equations, and I would like the subnumbering to continue across them. I.e.

> x = y + 1                             (1)
>
> It can be shown that x = 4, therefore
>
> y = 3                                 (1a)

(Ignore the non-right aligned numbering)

If I try the approach in the linked question (using `\begin{subequations}` and `tag{}`) I cannot seem to have the numbering continue as above, and instead the numbering resets (example below)

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:foo}
\begin{alignat}{2}
x = y + 1  \tag{\ref{eon:foo}} \\
\text{It can be shown that x = 4, therefore} \\
y = 3  
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

giving

> x = y + 1                             (1)
>
> It can be shown that x = 4, therefore (1a)
>
> y = 3                                 (1b)

How do I make the numbering continue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Before the second equation, insert `\addtocounter{equation}{-1}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you kindly add your own answer and then I'll remove mine? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano -- Leave your answer.  I just realized that an `align` environment is wanted, and alignment won't be accomplished by what I suggested.  (Since I don't at the moment have a tex system available, I can't experiment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My welcome to the TeX.SE. This is a fast answer but it not is a good answer with a lot of sincerity because you should put a new counter for `subequations` and equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:foo}
\begin{alignat}{2}
x = y + 1  \tag{1} \\
\intertext{It can be shown that $x = 4$, therefore} \nonumber\\
y = 3  
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```